# Unable to connect with plink with public/private key's

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

I am able to connect with Putty with my public/private key without being prompted for the passphrase (or password). I have pageant running in the background.

However, trying to connect with plink won't work (form the same windows machine) :(... It is telling me that the key is refused by the server :(.. See the output below.

Any idea why?

```
C:\Windows\System32>plink -v -agent -i C:\Users\ed\.ssh\id_rsa.pkk ed@bla.nl
Looking up host "bla.nl"
Connecting to 82.94.165.254 port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.62
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-1
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 83:15:11:84:8f:d8:f9:3a:16:b0:e4:8d:ef:4c:18:c4
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA1 server->client MAC algorithm
Reading private key file "C:\Users\ed\.ssh\id_rsa.pkk"
Unable to use this key file (unable to open file)
Unable to use key file "C:\Users\ed\.ssh\id_rsa.pkk" (unable to open file)
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Using username "ed".
Trying Pageant key #0
Server refused our key
Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
Attempting GSSAPI authentication
GSSAPI authentication request refused
ed@bla.nl's password:
```

Answer (score 4):

The first error message says it's not finding the key file you're trying to pass it. Might the problem be that the name ends in .ppk, not .pkk?